# How to evaluate integral volume

Tags: calculus

How to evaluate integral volume

$R$ is the finite region bounded by $x=y$ and $x=4y-y^2$

I do not understand where the area start and end. According to solution manual $V=2\pi\int_0^3...$

Where does $2\pi$ come from? Usually I just use $\pi$.

Comment: What does the $\cdots$ mean? Also how is it a volume? There are only two variables.

Comment: Hint: cylindrical method versus shell method.

Comment: Is this a solid of revolution around $Oy$? If so the answer is 8.1

Comment: Welcome to MSE. Please learn [how to ask a question](https://math.stackexchange.com/help/how-to-ask) before posting.

Comment: So basically you want the area between [the parabola and the line](https://ibb.co/mxtgoG) ? Or you are talking about a 3D volume ? In which case you need to give more details because what you describe is not "3D".

Comment: Please post the full question, otherwise is not clear what you're asking.

Comment: The rotation is around the x-axis. It is not a shell method

Comment: @J.Doe I have adapted my answer to the rotation around $x$-axis. Next time please specify it in the question :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

$x=4y-y^2$ intersects $y=x$ thus

$x=4x-x^2\to x^2-3x=0\to x_1=0;\;x_2=3$

$y=2\pm\sqrt{4-x}$

$$V=\int _{a}^{b}\pi \left(f(x)^{2}-g(x)^{2}\right)dx$$
that is
$$V=\pi\left[\int_0^3\,\left(x^2-(2-\sqrt{4-x})^2\right)\,dx +\int_3^4\,\left((2+\sqrt{4-x})^2-x^2\right)\,dx\right]$$
$$V=\pi\left[\int_0^3\,\left(x^2+x+4 \sqrt{4-x}-8\right)\,dx +\int_3^4\,\left(x^2+x-4 \sqrt{4-x}-8\right)\,dx\right]$$
$$V=\pi\left(\left\vert \frac{x^3}{3}+\frac{x^2}{2}+\frac{1}{3} (-8) (4-x)^{3/2}-8 x\right\vert_0^3+\left\vert \frac{x^3}{3}+\frac{x^2}{2}+\frac{8}{3} (4-x)^{3/2}+8 (4-x)\right\vert_3^4\right)=\\V=3\pi$$
Hope this helps

$$...$$

[image]

Comment: How did you make that graph ?

Comment: @A---B Geogebra for the curves and GIMP for the hatch